# how to set div height to first two lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div with some variable text, but I want to show only first two lines of text, so I need to set div height to match first two lines, and overflow hidden for rest.

This is easy to do with px but I am making it for smartphones so I would prefer to use "medium, large, small, x-large" font sizes. Is there a way to get the height of first two lines? Or any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you use `em` on mobile devices?

Comment: I don't know if em is precise enough, if lines are not cut precisely, tip of third line can be seen and it looks bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to estimate the height of each line , maybe this code helpful for you :

```
var fontSize = $(your-div).css('font-size');
var lineHeight = Math.floor(parseInt(fontSize.replace('px','')) * 1.5);
```

Then you can calculate two or more line height.
Maybe [this link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/20/typographic-design-survey-best-practices-from-the-best-blogs/#optimal) is helpful too.

Comment: You don't need to replace `'px'` with an empty string. `parseInt` already ignores all non-numeric characters after a number, as long as the string starts with a number (or with whitespace and then a number). Just doing `parseInt('100px')` returns `100`.